# Is there an intersection at the origin of the graph: $r=2+3cos\theta$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graph-theory, polar-coordinates

**Question**

Is there an intersection at the origin of the graph: $r=2+3cos\theta$

I have realized that if I was to graph the equation into a graphing calculator and zoom at the pole, there were no intersection at the point but then I thought this was strange so I did some calculations

I know that if r=0 then that is an intersection at the pole so I set it to 0 and realize that it is possible to get a value $\theta$ which satisfies r being zero,

Why does the calculator show otherwise?

Comment: I don't think one can answer the question without knowing something about your specific calculator and how you used it... There is definitely an intersection and Wolfram Alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r+%3D+2+%2B+3+cos(t)) shows you that.

Comment: Can we see waht the calculator graph looks like?

Comment: it is desmos.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we plot the graph:

[image]

We see there is in fact an intersection at $r=0$. The graphing calculator you used probably did a cartesian plot.